# How to use the same id for 2 views of different types

Tags: android

I have 2 scroll views, one in portrait layout, and the other in the horizontal layout (layout-land), and in onCreate I use findViewById using the shared id, the problem is, that one of them is ScrollView and the other is HorizontalScrollView which causes the following exception when I rotate the mobile:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/mainscreen_scrollview. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
```

The code behind the reason I gave the same ID for both ScrollViews, the code below is in onCreate(....)

```
    mHomeScrollView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainscreen_scrollview);

    mHomeScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Edit 1:

Based on the discussion with respectful members, seems that this is the most appropriate solution, I hope it might help others:

```
    int scrollViewId = R.id.mainscreen_scrollview;
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        scrollViewId = R.id.mainscreen_horizontalscrollview;
    }
```

Comment: You can check for device `orientation` in the `onCreate()`

Comment: Thank you @AbdulKawee I considered this as a last resort,

Comment: I can share you the spinet for this

Comment: Thank you @AbdulKawee I'm trying this approach right now, seems to be the only / appropriate approach

Comment: your welcome @Jack yeah it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken same `ScrollView id` for both of the `Scrollview`

**Error:**

> Make sure other views do not use the same id.

id is  `homescreen_scrollview`

**Note :** Both `scrollView` Id should be different.

Comment: Thanks, But I want them to be same so I can configure them during runtime

Comment: Why are you  using Same , Can you clarify? @Jack

Comment: mHomeScrollView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.homescreen_scrollview);

Comment: Why are you set id for both, without id you can use them. @Jack

Comment: Won't this cause an exception during runtime? as the layout-land won't be inflated when the device in portrait, which cause findViewById to return null

Comment: Then you should check the orientation @Jack

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this approach right now, seems to be the only / appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

By creating two layout files with the same name but in different directories (eg layout & layout_land) you can assign to the same object two identical ids. Simply set the id like `android:id="@+id/my_id"` to both. Be careful: Both have to be part of the same object (eg both ScrollViews).

Comment: It seems they must be of the same type, as in my case one is ScrollView and the other is HorizontalScrollView, and both derived from FrameLayout

Comment: Yes, check the last sentence of my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but you can try this and tell us if it work.

```
scrollView var1= (scrollview) var.findViewByID(R.id.first_scroll_view);

HorizontalScrollView  var2 = (HorizontalScrollView) var2.findViewByID(R.id.second_scroll_view)!
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have custom layout it's contains the toolbar with id = **tool_bar**.

when I include this layout, I give the same id for this include.

**wrong one**

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />
```

so, I will change this id to any other name to fix this issue

**Correct one**

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar_layout"
    layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />
```

So check the include ids not same as your child layout view ids.